# Spring 4 AOP aspect is never being called?

Tags: java, spring, aspectj, spring-4, aspect

I am using Spring 4 AOP and the aspect that i create is never being called and i cannot figure it out why is that. Look, i have this client class:

```
package com.example.aspects;

public class Client {


    public void talk(){

    }
}
```

And my aspect: 
    package com.example.aspects;

```
import org.aspectj.lang.JoinPoint;
@Aspect
public class AspectTest {

    @Before("execution(* com.example.aspects.Client.talk(..))") 
    public void doBefore(JoinPoint joinPoint) {
        System.out.println("***AspectJ*** DoBefore() is running!! intercepted : " + joinPoint.getSignature().getName());
    }

}
```

My configuration file:

```
package com.example.aspects;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.EnableAspectJAutoProxy;

@Configuration
@EnableAspectJAutoProxy
public class Config {

    @Bean
    public Client client(){
        return new Client();
    }

}
```

And finally, de app

```
public class App {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        AnnotationConfigApplicationContext appContext = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(
                Config.class);
        Client client = (Client) appContext.getBean("client");
        client.talk();
    }
}
```

By this way, i never get "intercepted" by AspectTest doBefore() method. have you any idea about what is going on ? Regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You never registered your `@Aspect`. Add a corresponding bean

```
@Bean
public AspectTest aspect() {
    return new AspectTest();
}
```

You can also make your type a `@Component` and add an appropriate `@ComponentScan` in your `@Configuration` class.

Comment: I cant believe i didn't see it. It was soooo easy. Thanks!